# Adding a custom placeholder to django-cms

Tags: python, django, django-templates, placeholder, django-cms

I'm trying to create a custom placeholder to add an admin-editable section on a website. [Django-cms' documentation](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/placeholders.html) is really generic about what's to be done to add it.

The placeholder lives in a separate app, called *contacts*, already added to the *settings.py* file

Here's my code up to now (skipping imports to be less verbose):

**models.py**

```
class ContactsPlaceholder(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=700)
    # your fields
    my_placeholder = PlaceholderField('contacts_contactsplaceholder')
    # your methods

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Contacts Placeholder"
```

**views.py**

```
def contacts(request):
  # Load the the contacts from db
  contactsfields = ContactsField.objects.all()
  contacts_placeholder = ContactsPlaceholder.objects.all() 
  context = {"contactsfields" : contactsfields, "contacts_placeholder" : contacts_placeholder}
  return render(request, "../templates/contacts.html", context) 

def contacts_placeholder_detail(request, id): # is this really useful?
  object = get_object_or_404(ContactsPlaceholder, id=id)
  return render_to_response('../templates/contacts_placeholder_detail.html', {
      'object': object,
  }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**contacts.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div>
  <h1>Contacts</h1>

  {% placeholder "contacts_placeholder" or %}
   <p>Placeholder is empty</p>
  {% endplaceholder %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and finally, **admin.py**

```
class ContactsPlaceholderAdmin(PlaceholderAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Editable fields
    frontend_editable_fields = ("phone", "email", "address")
    # Form fields order and sections
    fieldsets = [
        (None,{"fields" : ["phone", "email", "address"]})
    ]

admin.site.register(ContactsPlaceholder, ContactsPlaceholderAdmin)
```

With this configuration, after having run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I do get "Placeholder is empty" in the html response, and of course the placeholder is not editable using the standard frontend editor, which was the desired behaviour.

Going to *127.0.0.1:8000/admin/* i can see the "Contacts Placeholder" table, however when I click it or try to add items I do get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /us/admin/contacts/contactsplaceholder/
no such column: contacts_contactsplaceholder.phone
```

Comment: did you add the phone column after running syncdb ?

Comment: @Paulo I tried running syncdb, nothing changed..

Comment: that's what I mean, django won't update your tables once you've ran syncdb the first time. you have to do it manually or south

Comment: @Paulo doing that I can now finally open the "Contacts Placeholder" table on /admin, but even if I add one entry from there it will still show 'Placeholder is empty' when visiting the contacts page. I suspect the code in views.py is the problem now?

Comment: if i am understanding your problem correctly.. Use the template tag: render_placeholder from cms_tags. 

{% render_placeholder object.my_placeholder %}

Answer (score 2):

If the `contacts()` view is rendered via an app hook then using `{% placeholder "contacts_placeholder" %}` in the template won't work.

When using Placeholders in apps connected to the CMS via an AppHook you must use `{% static_placeholder "MyPlaceholder" %}` instead of the usual `{% placeholder "MyPlaceholder" %}`

If you've got an app or a plugin in which you've created a PlaceholderField, then in your template which renders that, you'd need the following tag;

```
{% render_placeholder instance.placeholderfieldname %}
```